# Retrieve all cart data for logged in customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, quote, quoteitem

I need to process all stored cart data that exists in magento site for logged in customer, is there any function to retrieve this data ?

Comment: Are you want to get cart items of customer using customer id?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i want to retrieve all carts which belongs to logged in customer and not yet checkout their cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code return all active quote for logged in customer only, Active means this quote are abandoned.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection $quoteCollection
) {
    $this->quoteCollection = $quoteCollection;
}
```

Now you use:

```
$quoteCollection = $this->quoteCollection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', 1);
$quoteCollection->getSelect()->join(
    'customer_entity',
    'main_table.customer_id=customer_entity.entity_id'
);
```

Now you have quote object.

Comment: i believe that's for magento 1, what i'm looking for magento 2

Comment: Uhh, wait then.

Comment: how can i know if the quote is already checked out or not?

Comment: If customer place order, then magento inactivated related quote. Active quote means customer add to cart not order place yet.

Comment: how to retrieve all the items in the cart?